# Can someone help me find what is wrong with the shiny app code?

Tags: r, shiny

When running, the submit button wont work but the app is there.
If someone could help with figuring out the submit to get it to run that would be great.
I dont think most people would know what open-air is but you don't need it just the shiny app part is the broken part I believe.

```
library(shiny)
library(openair)

# Load the AC_1 dataset
data("AC_1")

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("OpenAir Date Range and Chart Type Selection with Zoom"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      dateRangeInput("date_range", "Select Date Range:",
                     start = "2022-03-01", end = "2022-10-31",
                     format = "yyyy-mm-dd"),
      
      selectInput("chart_type", "Select Chart Type:",
                  choices = c("timePlot", "scatterPlot", "polarPlot", "rosePlot"),
                  selected = "timePlot"),
      
      actionButton("submit", "Submit"),
      
      # Zoom Slider
      sliderInput("zoom", "Zoom:", min = 1, max = 10, value = 5)
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("openair_plot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  selected_data <- reactive({
    # Filter data based on selected date range
    subset(AC_1, Date >= input$date_range[1] & Date <= input$date_range[2])
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    # Determine the chart type and create the corresponding plot
    output$openair_plot <- renderPlot({
      if (input$chart_type == "timePlot") {
        timePlot(selected_data(), pollutant = "VOC", zoom = input$zoom)
      } else if (input$chart_type == "scatterPlot") {
        scatterPlot(selected_data(), x = "wind_speed", y = "VOC", zoom = input$zoom)
      } else if (input$chart_type == "polarPlot") {
        polarPlot(selected_data(), pollutant = "VOC", zoom = input$zoom)
      } else if (input$chart_type == "rosePlot") {
        rosePlot(selected_data(), pollutant = "VOC", zoom = input$zoom)
      }
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You're trying to use a dataset "AC_1" (`data("AC_1")`) but the only sample data supplied with {openair} is called "mydata" (https://davidcarslaw.github.io/openair/reference/mydata.html ). Also, the plot function `rosePlot` doesn't exist (any longer?) but there are other rose plot functions: https://davidcarslaw.github.io/openair/reference/index.html#polar-analysis . Long story short: the submit button does what it should, but it tries to trigger functions on data neither of which are part of the recent {openair}: https://davidcarslaw.github.io/openair/index.html

Comment: AC_1 is a dataset that I imported in

Comment: I changed the roseplot to pollution rose but still no luck

Comment: While testing the app keep an eye on the server messages as they scroll by on the console. Shiny delivers quite concise and descriptive errors and warnings - that's how I found out about the missing dataset and functions anyway (e.g. `couldn't find function "rosePlot"`). Try resolving them one at a time. If unsuccessful (after investing some effort), it's best ask for help with a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example of each issue.

Comment: Im not getting any errors