# Shiny APP Submit Button is not doing anything

Tags: r, shiny

The app is non reactive and the submit doesn't do anything. I am not getting any error messages. If someone could look over it and see that would be great. I can also send over the data file if you could do some testing. Thank you!

```
library(shiny)
library(openair)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("OpenAir Date Range and Chart Type Selection with Zoom"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      # File input to select CSV file
      fileInput("file", "Select a CSV file:",
                accept = c(".csv")),
      
      dateRangeInput("date_range", "Select Date Range:",
                     start = "2022-03-01", end = "2022-09-31",
                     format = "yyyy-mm-dd"),
      
      selectInput("chart_type", "Select Chart Type:",
                  choices = c("timePlot", "scatterPlot", "polarPlot", "rosePlot"),
                  selected = "timePlot"),
      
      actionButton("submit", "Submit"),
      
      # Zoom Slider
      sliderInput("zoom", "Zoom:", min = 1, max = 10, value = 5)
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("openair_plot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  # Function to read the uploaded CSV file
  data <- reactive({
    req(input$file) # Make sure the file is selected
    df <- read.csv(input$file$datapath, header = TRUE)
    
    # Convert the first column to datetime format
    df[, 1] <- as.POSIXct(df[, 1], format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    
    return(df)
  })
  
  selected_data <- eventReactive(input$submit, {
    req(data()) # Make sure data is available
    # Filter data based on selected date range
    subset(data(), data()[, 1] >= input$date_range[1] & data()[, 1] <= input$date_range[2])
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    if (!is.null(selected_data())) {
      # Trigger plot rendering when both submit button and date range are selected
      if (input$chart_type == "timePlot") {
        timePlot(selected_data(), pollutant = "VOC", zoom = input$zoom)
      } else if (input$chart_type == "scatterPlot") {
        scatterPlot(selected_data(), x = "wind_speed", y = "VOC", zoom = input$zoom)
      } else if (input$chart_type == "polarPlot") {
        polarPlot(selected_data(), pollutant = "VOC", zoom = input$zoom)
      } else if (input$chart_type == "pollutionRose") {
        pollutionRose(selected_data(), pollutant = "VOC", zoom = input$zoom)
      }
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I have tried many things and cant figure it out. The app is supposed to let me to select a CSV file then a date range then a plot type

Comment: Please read in the (dummy) data and share some minimal example using `dput()` or something similar, which we can write to a `.csv`. Don't send any links to files or something.

Comment: Also, isn't this more or less a duplicate to your [last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76756206/can-someone-help-me-find-what-is-wrong-with-the-shiny-app-code) question?

Answer (score 0):

Although is difficult to know for sure since you are not providing any data, I think the problem is in `plotOutput("openair_plot")`: the `renderPlot` you are creating is called "*plot*" (`output$plot`), not "*openair_plot*".

Change the `plotOutput` in the `ui` for:

```
mainPanel(
  plotOutput("plot")
)
```

and check if that solves it.